# How to print first sentence from semicolon separated string?

Tags: javascript

I have a column in database table that saves type string in it. It saves multiple lines separated by semicolon, something like this -

```
this is first sentence;this is second sentence;this is third sentence
```

I want to print first line only, i.e. -

```
this is first sentence
```

Any idea how can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.split`

```js
const string ='this is first sentence;this is second sentence;this is third sentence'
const sentences = string.split(';')
const first = sentences[0]
console.log(first)
```